# Parse expression with binary and unary operators, reserved words, and without parentheses

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing, amazon-s3-select

I'm trying to parse expressions made of the binary operator `+`, the unary operator `not` and identifiers that can be any alphabetical string that isn't `not`

```py
from pyparsing import (
    CaselessKeyword,
    Combine,
    Word,
    alphas,
    opAssoc,
    infixNotation,
)

identifier = Combine(~CaselessKeyword('not') + Word(alphas))
expression = infixNotation(identifier, [
  ('+', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
  (CaselessKeyword('not'), 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
]
```

Running

```py
expression.parseString('a + (not b)')
```

gives what I expect

```py
[['a', '+', ['not', 'b']]]
```

However, without the parentheses

```py
expression.parseString('a + not b')
```

I only get the first token:

```py
['a']
```

How can I define the language to work as I would like without the parentheses?

(In the real case there are more operators and reserved words: this is a step towards parsing the S3 Select language)

Comment: 'not' should have higher precedence than '+' - just reverse the order of the two lines in the list you are passing to `infixNotation`.

Comment: @PaulMcG I think that causes the language to be different? For example, `'not a + b'` gets parsed differently depending on the precedence order. Note: what I'm actually doing is trying to parse the S3 Select language, where `NOT` is listed as a lower than the binary `+` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-operators.html

Comment: Do you insist on the use of pyparsing or would a different parsing framework be acceptable?

Comment: @rici Another parsing framework would be acceptable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In S3 `NOT` is **higher** that `AND`:

> **Operator Precedence**
> The following table shows the operators' precedence in decreasing order.

(from [S3 amazon site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-operators.html)).

In that table `NOT` is **above** `AND`.

So your code should be:

```py
identifier = Combine(~CaselessKeyword('not') + Word(alphas))
expression = infixNotation(identifier, [
    (CaselessKeyword('not'), 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
    ('+', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
])
```

BTW - If "`NOT` is listed as a lower than the binary `+`", than `a + not b` is not valid expression. `+` needs two operators: one is `a`, but `not b` is not valid operand.

BTW2 (from comments):
Please don't mix `+` which is an arithmetic operator and `NOT` which is a logic operator in the same expression. `1 + not 2` is not a valid expression.
Every language decide how to parse that's kinds of strange expressions.

Comment: "In S3 `NOT` is higher that `+`" the table is in decreasing order, so the operators further down the table are lower than those higher, so `NOT` is _lower_ than `+` in S3? Also, how is `AND` involved? And... why would `not b` not be a valid operand to `+` in `a + not b`? Instinctively to me somehow, it has to be equivalent to `a + (not b)`...

Comment: You can't mix `+` which is arithmetic operation and `NOT` which is logic is same expression. `1 + not 2` is not valid. I think this is the misunderstand here. (I edit my typo in my answer).

Comment: Ah: so understood that the expression may not make sense in terms of types. However, that should be a phase after parsing of the expression? In several languages, you _can_ apply `NOT` to a number, e.g. in Python `not 3 + 2` is fine. Note also, swapping the order of precedence makes `not 3 + 2` get parsed differently, so it feels, well, wrong, if trying to parse a language specified to have the original order?

Comment: In python you can write `not 2` but it has different meaning: `2` is parse as `True` so `not True` is `False`, that's why `not 0` is `True`. 
Every language decide how to parse that's kinds of expressions.

Comment: The best way I have found to address BTW2 is to break the infixNotation expression up into an arithmetic_expr (using just arithmetic operators), a comparison_expr (using `=`, `!=`, `>` etc.) operators, and logical_expr (using just NOT,  AND, and OR). Doing this work in the BNF up front will also help.